# Excel line plotted graph changes when horizontal axis is changed to Date

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have always experienced a frustrating problem when plotting line graphs. The plotted lines are smooth as they should be, but I would still need to tweak the horizontal axis to Date in order to show the days/months correctly.

But, when I format the horizontal axis to "Date Axis", the plotted line in the graph becomes jittery and rugged. (The lines becomes smooth again when I format the horizontal axis to "Text Axis" though this would, in turn, mess the day/date display).

I have attached an image of a graph before and after changing the horizontal axis to Date. This has been a nagging problem, so you could not imagine how grateful I'd be if someone would provide me with a solution that permits me to retain the smooth plot whilst with a horizontal Date

[image: Before and After Changing Horizontal Axis to Date]